# How to use parameters in a graphql query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, graphql, apollo

Hi im a bit new in react and graphql, everything is working nice but i dont get how i can pass parameters to a query

i need some help

```js
import React from 'react';
import { gql, graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const CourseForm = ({ data: {loading, error, getData }}) => {

  const testVariable = 2;
  console.log(getData);

  return (
  
    <form >
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="label-control">test</label>
      <input type="text" className="form-control"/>


    </div>

    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">
      Save
    </button>
  </form>);
}

const testQuery = gql`
query getData($id: Int!){
  getData(id: $id) {
    id, field {
      id
    }
  }
}
`;

const test = graphql(
  testQuery,{
  options: { variables: { id: 1 } }}
)(CourseForm);

export default test;
```

for example how can i use testVariable value in my query? to fetch data with id 2

i have seen some snippets using ownProps but i dont understand it, should i use props? i feel a bit lost

Thanks guys!

Comment: As your code is written now, it requires more than a few changes. Can you please provide a more concrete example or explanation of what you are trying to achieve? That will help pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: im trying to fetch the data from testQuery with id 2 then show it in a form, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use props like in this examples:

```html
// The caller could do something like:
<ProfileWithData avatarSize={300} />

// And our HOC could look like:
const ProfileWithData = graphql(CurrentUserForLayout, {
  options: ({ avatarSize }) => ({ variables: { avatarSize } }),
})(Profile);
```